# Bound on partition growth

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, group-theory, ergodic-theory

I asked a question about entropy here

[entropy of skew product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322543/entropy-of-skew-product)

but I think it might me a little too esoteric so I'm going to try and rephrase it.  Let $Y$ be a compact group, and suppose that $\beta$ is a finite partition of $Y$, meaning that $Y$ is the union of all elements of $\beta$ and the elements of $\beta$ are pairwise disjoint.  For two partitions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ define $\beta \vee \alpha=\{A_i \cap B_j : A_i \in \alpha, B_j \in \beta\}$.  Let $g_i \in Y$ and consider $\beta_1^n=g_1 \beta \vee g_1g_2 \beta \vee \dots \vee g_1g_2 \dots g_n \beta$.  Are there constants $K$ and $m$ such that the number of elements of $\beta_1^n$ is bounded by $(Kn)^m$?  The end goal is to get some bound $M_n$ on the size of $\beta_1^n$ such that $log(M_n)/n \to 0$

Comment: If this is merely a "rephrasing" of your previous question, you should delete your previous question.  Next time, edit a question if you want to rephrase it, at least if that question has not yet received answers.

Comment: I'm going to keep the other question up, it's interesting in it's own right and I can publish a complete solution there.